# Validação de e-mail via jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, magento

Estou tentando fazer uma validação em um campo de e-mail, eu até "consigo" fazer, mas não está 100% funcional, eu gostaria de cancelar o botão com o atributo disabled, até o usuario colocar uma e-mail válido, consigo o cancelamento do botão, mas quando digito o e-mail correto ele não volta.

**Input e botão**

```
<div>
    <input value="Digite seu e-mail" onclick="this.value=='Digite seu e-mail'?this.value='':''" onblur="this.value==''?this.value='Digite seu e-mail':''" type="text" name="email" id="newsletter" title="Assine nossa newsletter" class="input-text required-entry validate-email input-news validatex"/>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="button btn-inline news-button" id="validatex"><span>Enviar</span></button>
```

**Função**

```
function validateEmail(email) {
    var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
}

function validatex() {
  if (validateEmail(email)) {
    $j('#validatex').removeAttr('disabled');
    $j("#newsletter").css("background", "none");
    return true;
  } else {  
    $j("#newsletter").css("background", "url(../../skin/frontend/ultimo/default/images/icon-erro.png) no-repeat 330px #fff"); 
    $j('#validatex').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); 
    return false;
  }

}

$j(".validatex").bind("blur", validatex);
$j("#validatex").bind("click", validatex);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa usar evento de keyuo no input e ir verificando o conteudo do input.

O exemplo do codigo abaixo funcionando
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oGEoXz?editors=1011

```
<input type="email" >
<button>Enviar</button>
```

Seu JavaScript. A cada vez que usuario digita é feita a validação do valor que esta no input, uma vez que esse conteudo se torna um e-mail valido nos removemos os atributos de disabled.

```
function isEmail(email) {
  var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
  return regex.test(email);
}

$('document').ready(function(){
  $('button').attr('disabled','disabled');
  $('input').keyup(function(){
    if (isEmail($(this).val())){
      console.log('email valido')
      $('button').removeAttr('disabled');
    }else{
       $('button').attr('disabled','disabled');
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Deu certo, mas eu não gostaria de vir com o botão desabilitado, eu gostaria de deixar ele habilitado para o cliente clicar e receber a mensagem de erro para saber que tem de ser preenchido, mas ele faz exatamente o que preciso..

Comment: Basta que você remova a linha `$('button').attr('disabled','disabled');` antes do keyup, assim o botã não ira iniciar desabilitado. Depois só fazer validação ali dentro. Colocando campo `type="email" required` já deve resolver um pouco pra voce.